# Indy IMAP4 does not display German symbols correctly

Tags: delphi, gmail, indy, indy10

I am using TIdIMAP4 component to fill the string grid with the messages of my GMail mailbox.

```
var IMAPClient: TIdIMAP4;
```

Some messages have German umlauts. When I call IMAPClient.**RetrieveAllHeaders**(MyMsgList) the string grid is populated as expected (all umlauts are displayed) but there are no UIDs however (I guess that RetrieveAllHeaders just doesn't fetch UIDs).

When I call IMAPClient.**UIDRetrieveAllEnvelopes**(MyMsgList) all additional attributes of a Messages are there, but the headers are displayed in abracadabra (=?ISO-8859-1?Q?_Die_Br=FCcke_von_Arnheim?=) *// Shall be 'Die Brücke von Arnheim'*.

I've read many supportive posts but could not find the answer why IndyIMAP4 treats German symbols incorrectly.
Any ideas?

Comment: Will it help us to know which version of Delphi you use?

Comment: Maybe this can help [Encoding of Outbound Email from Gmail](http://robfairman.com/blog/encoding-of-outbound-email-from-gmail/)

Comment: @moskito-x: that has nothing to do with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RetrieveAllHeaders()` decodes the raw data it retrieves. `UIDRetrieveAllEnvelopes()` retrieves the raw data only, it does not decode. You can decode the raw headers manually by calling Indy's `DecodeHeader()` function in the `IdCoderHeader` unit.